# How many runs can a player score in 50 over match?

Tags: cricket

How many runs can a single player score in one day match (50 overs/300balls)?

No 'no balls', no wides, no extras, and no overthrows.

And one more last condition: they cannot run more than 3 for any ball.

Comment: Appalling and pointless question - it's about maths, not cricket. Do the sums yourself

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about doing some math equation rather than purely a sports-related question.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that (s)he starts on strike, hits 5 sixes and then runs 3 for the 6th ball, so constantly on strike. (S)He does this every over, (s)he scores `33*50=1650`!!!

(S)He hits the final ball for 6 instead of 3 as no longer needs to maintain the strike, bringing the total to 1653!

Comment: Why not hit the last ball of the 50th over for 6? That would give 3 more.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there is no maximum as the player can run an unlimited number of runs per ball providing that the ball remains within the boundary.

This would require a very poor fielding performance but technically possible.